# Windows Program in C Not Working

Tags: c, windows

I need to make a few programs in C and i cannot get the window to work. Its come up with about 30 errors mostly saying ; is expected when there is one there,  no storage class or type specifier, and declaration expected, not sure what these mean.  I have looked at two turtorials and they both look extremely similar and mine looks the same, so not sure what these missing things are.

Heres my code

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, 
                         HINSTANCE hPrevInst, 
                         LPSTR lpszArgs, 
                         int nWinMode);

{
WNDCLASS wcls;
HWND hwnd;
MSG msg;

LPCWSTR szClassName = L"ThreadsProgram";
LPCWSTR szWinName = L"My Threads Program"

    //Register Class
  wcls.style         =0; 
  wcls.lpfnWndProc   =WindowFunc;
  wcls.cbClsExtra    =0;
  wcls.cbWndExtra    =0;
  wcls.hInstance     =hThisInst;
  wcls.hIcon         =LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wcls.hCursor       =LoadCurser(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcls.hbrBackground =(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
  wcls.lpszMenuName  =NULL;
  wcls.lpszClassName =szClassName;

      if(!RegisterClass(&wcls))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

//Make Window 
hwnd = CreateWindow(szClassName,
szWinName,
WS_OVERLAPPINGWINDOW,
100,
100,
400,
400,
HWND_DESKTOP,
NULL,
hThisInst,
NULL);

//Show Window

if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Failed!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

ShowWindow(hwnd, nWinMode);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

//Main Message Loop
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: "mostly saying ; is expected"... don't give us approximate errors. Show us the exact errors. Way easier to help you then. :) And could you please properly indent your code?

Comment: `LPCWSTR szWinName = L"My Threads Program"` missing semicolon. And the compiler reports missing semicolons ? * shocked *.

Comment: Well, this line at least is missing a semi-colon: LPCWSTR szWinName = L"My Threads Program"

Comment: Surely the compiler can help you find these problems?

Comment: Hint #1: The compiler will tell you which line it thinks has a problem. hint #2: If that line looks OK to you, look at the line before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of typos there.

1. semicolon after the WinMain
2. MessageBox() function taking 3 instead of 4 params.
3. LPWCSTR params
4. ShowWindow() with nCmdShow doesn't ... show
5. WS_OVERPLAPPEDWINDOW (not WS_OVERLAPPINGWINDOW)
6. LoadCursor instread of LoadCurser

Should work now. Next time type carefully

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch(msg)
     {
         case WM_CLOSE: DestroyWindow(hwnd); break;
         case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
         default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
     }
     return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst,  HINSTANCE hPrevInst,  LPSTR lpszArgs,  int nWinMode)
{
    WNDCLASS wcls;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    LPCSTR szClassName = "ThreadsProgram";
    LPCSTR szWinName = "My Threads Program";

    //Register Class
    wcls.style         =0; 
    wcls.lpfnWndProc   =WindowFunc;
    wcls.cbClsExtra    =0;
    wcls.cbWndExtra    =0;
    wcls.hInstance     =hThisInst;
    wcls.hIcon         =LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcls.hCursor       =LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcls.hbrBackground =(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wcls.lpszMenuName  =NULL;
    wcls.lpszClassName =szClassName;

     if(!RegisterClassA(&wcls))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, 0, "Window Registration Failed!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    //Make Window 
    hwnd = CreateWindowA(szClassName, szWinName,
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
       100, 100, 400, 400,
       HWND_DESKTOP,
       NULL, hThisInst, NULL);

    //Show Window

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, 0, "Window Failed!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW/*nWinMode*/);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    //Main Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still 3 errors but i think i know what the problem is, ill try and fix it now.

Comment: I ran "gcc -o Test.exe Test.cpp -lstdc++ -lgdi32" on this code. It works. The only problem that might be here is that you're not trying the complete source and pasting the fixes line by line introducing new errors :)

Comment: No completely copied and pasted

Comment: IntelliSense: a value of type "LPCSTR" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR" 

IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" x 2 lines

Comment: See my edit once again (I changed the RegisterClassA, MessageBoxA calls). I'm not using VisualStudio and you just have a "Use Unicode strings" option set in your project. So change MessageBox to MessageBoxA explicitly (these are two error). Then RegisterClass to RegisterClassA.

Comment: Thanks
These 2 lines are showing as wrong

wcls.lpszClassName =szClassName; 
 
     if(!RegisterClassA(&wcls))

Comment: Are showing or were showing ? Does it aall work ? I check each change I make. It's only a GCC/MSVC++ issues.

Comment: Weee found it, it  WNDCLASS wcls; line

Comment: Sorry didnt know i needed to do that, im a bit new to here, Thanks very much for the help aswell.

Comment: I got lots more to do, just no idea where to start :(

Answer (score 3):

The first problem I see is here:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, 
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInst, 
                     LPSTR lpszArgs, 
                     int nWinMode);      /* <---- This semi-colon causes grief! */

{
WNDCLASS wcls;
```

You have a declaration of a function because of the semicolon after `int nWinMode);`.

Remove it.

There may also be other problems; I didn't look further and don't plan to do so.  The compiler will guide you if your own code review won't help.

Comment: Actually, just move the semicolon down 8 lines ;-)

Comment: It's not enough, plenty of errors there. And at the end the window won't show up because of the invalid nCmdShow (it is deprecated, as I remember).

Comment: Genny, see my answer - I've fixed everything. Even the ShowWindow() call which does not actually show the window.

Comment: Corrected the spelling mistake (cursor) added the missing semi colon to the window name.